# Custom control wpf, enabling invoking control methods to support MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am writing a custom control in WPF, and i have a couple of methods in the control that the user of my control can invoke.

Although it can be invoked directly, due to requests from users, i want to enable the control's methods to be invoked in a MVVM manner.

After research, i take it i have to implement ICommandSource on my control.
The MSDN has an example but i find it too much over-engineered for my situation (or maybe because i don;t understand it at all!).
All i want is to let my consumers to call my method via a command rather than put their calling code in view's code behind.

Please advise with a simple sample code to implement this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the Blend SDK is a behavior MethodInvoker (if my memory serves correct) that allows you to bind to a method. That way you do not have to implement ICommand.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to reflect over the .NET code (or you can download the .NET source code via [download](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx)) look into how MS does it with ButtonBase. Yes, there is a lot of code under the hood, but that's because if you're going to create a custom control you should account for both scenarios of RoutedEvents and Commands.